# How to convert query ' WHERE IN' of strings with TypeORM Query Builder?

Tags: sql-server, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

Getting errors in following TypeORM query:

```
async exportUsers(stateId: string, zipcodes: string) 
{
  //zipcodes = '60563', '54656', '94087';//
  const query = await this.userRepository
  .createQueryBuilder('user')
  .select('user.email', 'email')
  .where('left(user.Zip,5) in :zip', { zip: zipcodes }); 
}
```

How to pass string containing 'array of strings' to TypeORM query using IN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked:

```
zipcodes = '60563', '54656', '94087';
const ziplist: string[] = zipcodes.replace("'", "").split(",");
```

Changed query to:

```
.where('left(s.ShipToZip,5) in (:...zip)', { zip: ziplist });
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your where clause with this code:

```
.where("left(user.Zip,5) IN (:zip )", { zip : zipcodes })
```

**Note: your zipcode variable should be in array format; in means:**

```
zipcodes = ['94085','54656','94087']
```